# How to avoid dhclient default gateway on an interface

Tags: dhcp, dhclient

Here is an issue I have stumbled uppon a couple of times and for which I still have no solution.
I have a NetworkManager managed box with two interfaces. Let's call them *eth0* and *eth1*.
Both NEED to get ip over dhcp, and they both add their default gateway.
What I would like is to have one of them not applying the default gw.

In the last iteration of this situation I learned that NetworkManager creates a 
*/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-eth0.conf* from */etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf*.

Is this a missing feature of NetworkManager or I should try to create a new *dhclient.conf* that contains dhcp request information for each iface with different request sections?

Answer (score 9):

## Short answer

```bash
nmcli connection modify id 'My eth1 connection' ipv4.never-default yes
```

Read on for the longer answer and some alternatives. In all cases you have to restart connections to get the change.

### Network Manager: `ipv4.never-default`

There's such a feature in NetworkManager. If you want to limit eth1 which is for example called `My eth1 connection`, graphically it's accessible with `Edit Connections > My eth1 connection > IPV4 Settings > Routes`

There are two toggles:

- "Ignore automatically obtained routes". Its nmcli equivalent:

  ```
   nmcli connection modify id 'My eth1 connection' ipv4.ignore-auto-routes yes
  ```
- "Use this connection only for resources on its network". Its nmcli equivalent is:

  ```
   nmcli connection modify id 'My eth1 connection' ipv4.never-default yes
  ```

The first option disables [classless static routes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3442), which are not commonly used, while the second disables the default [router](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132#section-3.5).

For most people the second option is sufficient. Ponder also setting the first: it might be useful and should not conflict.

### Another way: `dhclient.conf`

In `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` (but outside of NetworkManager's environment) you can add a stanza for an interface for this DHCP setup:

```
# Assign this interface an IP address only.
# (This disables setting the gateway router, DNS, domain, etc.)
interface "eth1" {
  request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, interface-mtu;
}
```

Note that this works by omitting parameters such as `rfc3442-classless-static-routes`, `routers`, and a few others.

### Yet another answer: `ipv4.route-metric`

Another method (that I didn't see in the graphical settings) would be increase the metric (thus lowering "priority") of a connection. By default it's automatic and it seems Wifi has a higher metric than Ethernet for example. With this you can have both default routes, but the second route isn't used until the first disappears. From [this description](https://web.archive.org/web/20220928021512/blog.felipe.lessa.nom.br/?p=129), to give priority to "My eth0 connection" over "My eth1 connection" that would be:

```
nmcli connection modify id 'My eth0 connection' ipv4.route-metric 100
nmcli connection modify id 'My eth1 connection' ipv4.route-metric 500
```

### One last possibility: use both at once

Yet another method to get your two DHCP connections fully working at the same time would be to setup [routing for multiple uplinks/providers](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html). With this and a few multipath routes or routing related firewall rules you can load-balance access and can combine both bandwidths, given enough connections to multiple destinations. But this would be more difficult to integrate correctly with NetworkManager + dhclient.

Comment: I like that this is a thorough answer which covers lots of different answers succinctly. I would, however, suggest that the answer for dhclient.conf is confusing than necessary as it refers to options (such as "routers") which do not help, in my experience. I will edit the answer to put in what does work.